# CSS3: calc not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, less, css-calc

I have a less class as a function. I use calc() to set scale value, it working on chrome but not Firefox. this is my class:

```
.zoom(@value) {
    transform: scaleX(@value);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(@value);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(@value);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(@value);
    transform-origin: 0;
    .blocFreq {
        &:before {
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-moz-calc(1/@value)) !important;
            -ms-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
            transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
        }
    }
    span.frequence {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value))rotate(-44deg) !important;
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-moz-calc(1/@value))rotate(-44deg) !important;
        -ms-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value))rotate(-44deg) !important;
        transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value))rotate(-44deg) !important; 
    }
    .text,
    .text-service,
    .popover {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
        -moz-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
        -o-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
        -ms-transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
        transform: scaleX(calc(1/@value)) !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to question but from what I see in your example, you might like to look at Compass or some other library that takes care of browser specific prefixes (meaning compatibility with less code to write).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove calc function and use only (1/@value). I think that will fix your bug.